# Is there any way that we can use Kafka streams for loading file to database?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

It can be any file. I just wanna know whether it's possible using Kafka stream.

Answer (score 0):

Use Kafka Connect's [JDBC Sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/index.html) to stream data from Kafka to a database.

Here's an example of it in use: https://rmoff.dev/kafka-jdbc-video

Comment: Thnks mate will give it a try.